# The limit of 20000 characters in post content was exceeded Wordpress after trying save page

Tags: wordpress

After saving page I got an error:
"The limit of 20000 characters in post content was exceeded" and can't save more.
Is it mysql limit or php or maybe some wordpress Constant limit?

Indeed I've got a lot of content / chars.

I ve tried increase `post_max_size` and `max_input_vars` in php.ini however without success.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Sounds weird, i've never seen that & have been working with Wordpress for 10+ years. The post_content field is a LongText & should hold 4,294,967,295 characters. I just did a search for the error in Wordpress and couldn't find it, maybe disable all plugins & themes & see if it still occurs or do a search for the error in your own codebase

Comment: Hmm... it's sth within wordpress files configuration: themes or plugins. I changed wordpress instalation and pasted the same content with no errors!

 So I will investiage in more depth! @admcfajn thx for Direction!!!

Comment: it was this code:


add_action('pre_post_update', function ($post_id, $data) {
    $max_allowed_characters = 200000;

    if (strlen($data{'post_content'}) > $max_allowed_characters) {
        wp_die(new WP_Error('character limit exceeded', "The limit of $max_allowed_characters characters in post content was exceeded", array('status' => 500)));

    }
}, 10, 2);

Comment: Thanks [Paweł Witek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7920853/paweł-witek), yeah that looks right. Where did you find that? wp-includes or wp-admin? Was the core of Wordpress modified? Hopefully you can get the custom code removed and/or refactored into a plugin so you can run updates rather than maintaining core independently.